# How to extends android.view.Surface?

Tags: java, android, class, graphics, sdk

I'm hitting an issue by trying to extends the Surface class of Android. My current snippet is:

```
import android.view.Surface;

public class PixelSurface extends Surface {
    public PixelSurface() {
        super();
    }
}
```

When i try to compile, the error is:

```
[javac] /home/tito/code/bleh/src/org/kivy/android/PixelSurface.java:5: Surface() is not public in android.view.Surface; cannot be accessed from outside package
[javac]             super();
```

What i don't understand is that on Surface.java of android, the method and the class is public (for example at: http://netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/Surface.java)

What did i miss ?

**Edit**: i don't want to use SurfaceView or GL or any "View" related. I'm trying to get the picture of a MediaPlayer in offscreen. My question is specific, and not standard android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want the GLSurfaceView? Has a bit more control. Otherwise you might be able to get the core classes and change them directly. It is not intended for you to use Surface though, so I recommend you look for an alternative, I'm sure there's a workaround

Answer (score 0):

You are extending the wrong class, you should extend SurfaceView

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

Surface is used internally by the Android system

Comment: No, i want to have an access to a buffer in a specific manner, this is not standard. SurfaceView cannot be used in my case.